# 405 (Method Not Allowed) - PUT

Tags: node.js, graphql, header

I am currently taking a NodeJS course and learning GraphQL.
The course instructed to set header on the server side like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  next();
```

However it keeps giving me a
`App.js:122          PUT http://localhost:8080/graphql 405 (Method Not Allowed)`
error.

I tried looking at the video multiple times and looking around for answers but found no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ..., PUT, ...` tells the browsers to allow cross-origin clients, i.e. a 3rd-party website from another domain, to send PUT requests to your backend service. This has nothing to do with the error response `405 (PUT) Method not allowed`.

The error `405 (PUT) Method not allowed` is returned by your Nodejs app because there is no actions to handle PUT requests to that path in your code.

GraphQL libraries typically use `POST`. Try sending `POST` requests to your GraphQL endpoint instead of `PUT`.

Comment: Thank you! I checked it again and realized I missed the step where the request is changed from PUT to POST.